# How to minimize the average distance between pumps and cities?

Tags: algorithm

We have to place pumps at cities in such a way that sum of distance between a city and its nearest pump is minimized.

Since the array is sorted , i am thinking of using binary search , but i could not get correct result using binary search . So i tried it using dynamic programming , i derived the recursive formula but could not code it.
[Recurrence Relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w78I.png)

I started to code but could not complete it.

Comment: What is the relation between cities, pumps and the array? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: 5 10 1 2 3 6 7 9 11 22 44 50 where 5 is the total number of pumps and 10 are the cities , so to minimize distance between each city and pump install pump at locations 2,7,11,22,50 the minimum distance comes to be 9.

Comment: Please edit your question so that others don't have to browse through the comments to understand. Is this from a coding website? If yes it would be good to provide the link to the question.